# Iptables kernel module in stock Arch

Tags: linux, iptables, arch-linux, kernel-module

When attempting to use iptables on an Arch install with the default kernel, I'm receiving the error

```
iptables v1.6.2: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I have no idea why the module wouldn't be installed, although I did experiment a little with nftables, perhaps that replaced something? Is this message correct and if so how do I go about fixing it?

EDIT:
Output of pacman -Qii

```
Name            : linux
Version         : 4.17.2-1
Description     : The Linux kernel and modules
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://www.kernel.org/
Licenses        : GPL2
Groups          : base
Provides        : None
Depends On      : coreutils  linux-firmware  kmod  mkinitcpio>=0.7
Optional Deps   : crda: to set the correct wireless channels of your country
Required By     : None
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 114.63 MiB
Packager        : Jan Alexander Steffens (heftig) <jan.steffens@gmail.com>
Build Date      : Sat Jun 16 12:08:26 2018
Install Date    : Wed Jun 20 05:02:18 2018
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : Yes
Validated By    : Signature
Backup Files    :
UNMODIFIED      /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset
```

Comment: What is your kernel version? What command do you use? Do you run that as root? Have you restarted your machine after upgrading the kernel? I have `linux 4.16.8-1` installed and the module  `iptable_filter` is present on my system.

Comment: @KamilCuk `4.16.12-12-1-ARCH` I've used both `sudo iptables -S` and `sudo iptables -L`. I used `modprobe iptables; modprobe iptables_filter; modprobe iptables-filter; modprobe ip_tables` all to no avail.

Comment: It's `iptable_filter` (without 's'). What folders do you have in /usr/lib/modules, ie. what is the output of `ls /usr/lib/modules`? Can you search for iptable_filter in /usr/lib/modules, ie. post the output of `find /usr/lib/modules/ -name 'iptable_filter.ko.xz'`?

Comment: Wait, why do you have double `12` in kernel version, ie. `4.16.12-12-1-ARCH`? Shouldn't it be `4.16.12-1-ARCH` ? You got to have /usr/lib/modules/*/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko.xz, it's in the package listing. Have you tried reinstalling core/linux package, ie. `pacman -S linux`? Do you kernel installed from core repository? Can you post the output of `pacman -Qii linux` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk sorry that's a typo. The search returned `/usr/lib/modules/4.17.2-1-ARCH/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko.xz`. I ran the Qii command. I will edit it into the main question. I can try the install however I am not at my desk until monday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running on kernel `4.16.12`, but you have updated kernel to `4.17.2`.  After each kernel upgrade you need to restart your machine.
iptable fails, because it tries to load module `iptable_filter`, however the file `/usr/lib/modules/4.16.12-1-ARCH/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_filter.ko.xz` no longer exists, because you have updated your kernel with `pacman -S linux`. To change the running kernel you need to restart your machine. After restart, if the running kernel as reported by `uname -a` matches the version that is installed `pacman -Q linux`, then the `iptables` command should successfully load `iptable_filter` module.

Comment: Ah, I have a systemd task that updates at 5am it must have updated the kernel without my knowledge. Thanks!